# Why when using httpclient it's not downloading multiple files from a list?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            // for the sake of the example lets add a client definition here
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
            var docUrl = "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin";
            //var filePath = @"d:\Test\100MB.bin";

            // Setup your progress reporter
            var progress = new Progress<float>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;

            for (int i = 0; i < videosLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                var filePath = @"d:\Test\" + i + ".mp4";
                try
                {
                    using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        await client.DownloadDataAsync(videosLinks[i], file, progress);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        void Progress_ProgressChanged(object sender, float progress)
        {
            // Do something with your progress
            progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DownloadFile();
        }
```

when i used only a single file download :

```
"https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin";
```

and instead the for loop just a single line :

```
using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                await client.DownloadDataAsync(docUrl, file, progress);
```

it was working fine and downloaded the big file with reporting to the progressBar.

but when i'm trying to download the files in the videosLinks List with the for loop it's just saving small files on the hard disk all the files same size 4.40KB and the downloaded files(mp4) should be in MB's it's just not downloading them.

i added a break point on the catch but it's never get there.
it's getting to the line :

```
using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        await client.DownloadDataAsync(videosLinks[i], file, progress);
```

not giving any errors or exceptions but not downloading the files.

i tried to add headers but it didn't change anything.

this is the class HttpClientProgressExtensions code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientProgress
{
    public static class HttpClientProgressExtensions
    {
        public static async Task DownloadDataAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, Stream destination, IProgress<float> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                using (var download = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    // no progress... no contentLength... very sad
                    if (progress is null || !contentLength.HasValue)
                    {
                        await download.CopyToAsync(destination);
                        return;
                    }
                    // Such progress and contentLength much reporting Wow!
                    var progressWrapper = new Progress<long>(totalBytes => progress.Report(GetProgressPercentage(totalBytes, contentLength.Value)));
                    await download.CopyToAsync(destination, 81920, progressWrapper, cancellationToken);
                }
            }

            float GetProgressPercentage(float totalBytes, float currentBytes) => (totalBytes / currentBytes) * 100f;
        }

        static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, IProgress<long> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (bufferSize < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));
            if (source is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (!source.CanRead)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(source)}' is not readable.");
            if (destination == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
            if (!destination.CanWrite)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(destination)}' is not writable.");

            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                progress?.Report(totalBytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'videosLinks' has downlodable file links ?

Comment: @Koks_rs yes i checked the list and took the first item link and i can play the video mp4 online.  and if there was a problem why it's not getting to the catch ?

Comment: @Koks_rs i tried now again this time without the loop only the first link in the list videosLinks[0] and it's not working either.

Comment: Try to create a new HttpClient(); for every request ?

Comment: @Koks_rs i found the solution.  i had to add headers like this : client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome"); and not like i did before.  now it's working.

Comment: lso try adding `useAsync: true` in the `FileStream` constructor

Comment: @Charlieface where do i add it in filestream constructor ? i tried in the end but it's not accepting anymore arguments.

Comment: `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 81920, true)`